# iOS in-apps "Purchase of this item is not currently available"

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

App keeps showing popup:
"Purchase of this item is not currently available.
This item is beign modified. Please try again later".

It causes not for all purchase attempts.
Sometimes, purchase successfully finished, so it does not depends on in-app product ID.

We uses Unity IAP 4.8.0 (also tried 4.1.5 and 4.9.3) as purchasing SDK.
XCode project built by Unity 2020.3.27f.

We have our server-side receipts validation, so client side pending before can finish any paid transaction.

I setuped App Store Connect for purchases:

1. Accept paid agreement (green active toggle enabled)
2. Create consumables with metadata (state for each is "ready to submit", all regions included (174), app setuped for 41 region)
3. Add In-App Purchases capability to XCode project and provision profiles.

I checked XCode console and saw error from storekitd:
`storekitd  AMSURLSession: [A14A38AA_SK1] Protocol completed with error. Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=305 "Server Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The purchase of the object is currently unavailable, AMSServerAllowed=false, AMSServerErrorCode=2040, AMSServerPayload={...}`

storekitd returns `SKErrorUnknown`.
Unity IAP also returns `PurchaseFailureReason.Unknown` and failure description `APPLE_An unknown error has occurred`.

No topics with solution hasn't been found about this store kit error.
We wrote to Apple Developer Support about this problem, but still didn't received any response.

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

We tried:

1. downrgaid Unity IAP to verified version 4.1.5
2. upgrade Unity IAP to latest version 4.9.3
3. create empty project is Unity IAP sample and our existing SKUs.
4. create new in-app product at App Store Connect

Comment: we found out that changing base price currency of in-app product fixes this issue

Comment: What new currency did you choose?